# How can I add a counting system to my game I made

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

I am a beginner and I code in C# console. I made this guessing game where you have to guess a random number from 1 to 10. I made this so you can play it infinite times. The game works perfectly as planned but I want something more in this game which is a counting system. I want my code to count the tries the player took to get a correct guess. I have tried several ways but it doesn't work.

```
using System;

namespace The_Test_Program
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Appearance
            Console.Title = "Test";
    
    // Working Code
    Console.WriteLine("I will generate a random number and you have to guess it.");
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNum = random.Next(1,11);
        
        Console.WriteLine("I have generated a random number from 1 to 10.");
        Console.Write("What do you think write the answer : ");
        int GenNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Char yN;

        while (GenNum!=randomNum)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("\nWrong");  
            Console.Write("Wanna try again [Y/N]: ");  
            yN = Char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (yN =='Y')
            {                    
                randomNum = random.Next(1,11);
                Console.WriteLine("I have generated a new random number.");
                Console.Write("Try again : ");
                GenNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No problem");
                Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to exit .....");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }    
        
        Console.WriteLine("Correct");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hello, you just need one int variable on the beginning of the code, then in while statement you should increase to count how many times he attempt to guess the number counter ++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly welcome to stack overflow, I hope you enjoy navigating it :)

I would suggest a few changes, you can change your while check to this:

```cs
while (GenNum!=randomNum && yN != 'N')
```

This will allow you to extract the if logic later on, and just loop while those two statements are correct.

If you want to count how many times it loops through (count how many times the player has played), you can add an `int counter` at the beginning and then add `counter++` in the while loop. The ++ is the same as `counter = counter + 1`, but in a more fancy way.

The code below with these points, there a few more things that you may want to change, but this is so you get the point!

```cs
using System;

namespace The_Test_Program
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Appearance
            Console.Title = "Test";
    
            // Working Code
            Console.WriteLine("I will generate a random number and you have to guess it.");
            Random random = new Random();
            int randomNum = random.Next(1,11);
            
            Console.WriteLine("I have generated a random number from 1 to 10.");
            Console.Write("What do you think write the answer : ");
            int GenNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Char yN = 'Y';
            int counter = 0;
    
            while (GenNum!=randomNum && yN != 'N')
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("\nWrong");
                Console.Write("Wanna try again [Y/N]: ");  
                yN = Char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                counter++;
                if (GenNum == randomNum)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Correct, you tried {counter} times.");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("No problem");
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to exit .....");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are some problems I found in your code. Firstly the counting works properly but the correct answer is not proper as you have to outputs but only one place to place output. The last console. Writeline doesn't work is out of main

Comment: Hi, I have edited the code. Give that a go and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your participation i made it using an int count